# extract the last 8 letters of string with substr

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get the last 9 characters of `$span`.

```
$span = "";
foreach($html->find('span') as $element1){
    
if (strpos($element1->outertext, 'kcal') !== false){
    $span .= $element1->outertext.'<br>';

}
    
}

echo substr($span,-9);
```

It just show me white page, any suggestions?

**Edit:**
When i debug with `var_dump($span)` it shows exactly the following:

```
string(761) " 1 Porsiyon (Orta) AnçuezSardalya Salatası 319 kcal 1 Su Bardağı Ayran (Yağsız) 41 kcal 1 Su Bardağı Anne Sütü 138 kcal 1 Porsiyon (Orta) Amasya Yöresine Özgü Keşkek 728 kcal 1 Porsiyon (Orta) Anne Kurabiyesi 504 kcal "
```

Comment: Have you tried basic debugging? What does `var_dump($span);` give you?

Comment: try to debug ur code dude!

Comment: echo substr(trim($span),-9);

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol i tried it. it gives string(159) for the first $span and second is string(178),  and it goes .. now what can i do ?

Comment: @HSSingh i tried

Comment: It should show more than that, like it should show the actual contents of the string...

Comment: @humam, what do you expect to see? please post the full contents of `var_dump($span);`

Comment: @humam,  From what I understand that you need, is to have the amount of calories (kcal) from each ingredient in a recipe. Is that right? In that case, post some of the html containing the list of ingredients. Because there is a lot of things that are wrong and pieces of information is missing. Like, var_dump is showing 761 characters when the string itself is much less (232 characters).

Answer (score 0):

use **trim()** to remove white spaces
so you can write

```
echo substr(trim($span),-9);
```

Comment: Could you `var_dump` the span?

Comment: What kind of person sees a question complaining about seeing nothing, and thinks "removing spaces" is a reasonable answer?

Comment: because he just sees the last characters,

Comment: So what do you see?

Comment: @Hamid i can not see anything just white page

Comment: @Hamid it gives string(159) for the first $span and second is string(178), and it goes ..

Comment: @humam You must be sure that you have a no empty array in `$html->find('span')`

Comment: @humam please add what you see in the result of var_dump in your question

Comment: @Hamid, could you please check now

Comment: @humam try `echo substr(strip_tags(trim($span)),-9);`

Comment: @ i want to get number beside kcal like this : 319 kcal with or without the word kcal

Comment: @Hamid still not working unfortunately still showing white page

Comment: @humam You have to debug your code step by step
after checking all content in `html->find`<br>
Now go inside of `foreach` and first check does execute your code inside of condition?<br> if so, Now `var_dump` content of `$element1->outertext`